# How should I fix my code to stop getting errors with the test code?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, computer-science

This assignment is about testing array. Here is my code, and we are supposed to get OK for all of the results when the test code that was given is run, but instead I am getting what I am posting below the code.
Any suggestions to fix?
Help please

```
    public class ArrayUtils 
{
    public static int minValue(int[] list) throws BadArrayException 
    {
        if(list == null)
            throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");
        else if(list.length == 0)
            throw new BadArrayException("Array is empty");

        int minValue = list[0];  
        for(int i=1; i < list.length; i++){  
            if(list[i] < minValue){  
            minValue = list[i];  
            } 
        }  
        return minValue; 
        }   


    public static int[] copyRange(int[] list, int startIndex)
            throws BadArrayException{
                if (list == null)
                    throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");
                else if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > list.length)
                    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(startIndex);
                else{
                    int [] newList = new int [list.length - startIndex];
                    int x = 0;
                    int i;
                    for (i = startIndex; i < list.length; i++)
                        if (startIndex == 0){
                            newList[i] = list[i];
                        }else{
                            newList[x] = list[i];
                            x += 1;
                        }
                    }
                int[] newList = null;
                return newList;
                }

    public static int indexOf(int[] list, int searchValue) throws BadArrayException 
    {
        int indexValue = 0;

        if(list == null)
            throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");
        else if(list.length == 0)
            return -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            if(list[i] == searchValue)
                indexValue = i;
        }
        return indexValue;
    }

    public static int lastIndexOf(int[] list, int searchValue) throws BadArrayException
    {
        int indexValue = 0;
        int last = list.length;

        if(list == null)
            throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");
        else if(list.length == 0)
            return -1;

        for(int i = last; i >= 0; i--){
            if(list[i] == searchValue)
                indexValue = i;
        }
        return indexValue;        
    }
}
```

Testing ArrayUtils class exception handling - 2/07/2014

--- Testing minValue method ---

Getting minVal of a null array
  OK - minValue threw exception for null array: BadArrayException

Getting minVal of an empty array
  OK - minValue threw exception for empty array: BadArrayException

Getting minVal() of: [10]
  OK - expected minValue to return 10 and got: 10

Getting minVal() of: [20,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return 20 and got: 20

Getting minVal() of: [40,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return 30 and got: 30

Getting minVal() of: [10,10]
  OK - expected minValue to return 10 and got: 10

Getting minVal() of: [15,25,35]
  OK - expected minValue to return 15 and got: 15

Getting minVal() of: [25,20,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return 20 and got: 20

Getting minVal() of: [50,40,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return 30 and got: 30

Getting minVal() of: [50,-10,40,-25,50,40,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return -25 and got: -25

Getting minVal() of: [200,50,-40,60,-15,30,75]
  OK - expected minValue to return -40 and got: -40

--- Testing copyRange method ---

Getting copyRange of a null array
  OK - copyRange threw exception for null array: BadArrayException

Getting copyRange(list,-1) of: []
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1

Getting copyRange(list,0) of: []
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 0 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,1) of: []
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1

Getting copyRange(list,-1) of: [20]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1

Getting copyRange(list,0) of: [20]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 1 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,1) of: [20]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 0 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,2) of: [20]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 2

Getting copyRange(list,-1) of: [10,15]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1

Getting copyRange(list,0) of: [10,15]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 2 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,1) of: [10,15]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 1 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,2) of: [10,15]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 0 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,3) of: [10,15]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 3

Getting copyRange(list,-1) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1

Getting copyRange(list,0) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 5 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,1) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 4 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,2) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 3 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,3) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 2 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,4) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 1 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,5) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  ERROR - expected copyRange to return an array of length 0 but got a null array

Getting copyRange(list,6) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 6

--- Testing indexOf and lastIndexOf method ---

Getting indexOf of a null array
  OK - indexOf threw exception for null array: BadArrayException

Getting lastIndexOf of a null array
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Getting indexOf(5) of: []
  OK - expected indexOf to return -1 and got: -1

Getting lastIndexOf(5) of: []
  OK - expected lastIndexOf to return -1 and got: -1

Getting indexOf(20) of: [20]
  OK - expected indexOf to return 0 and got: 0

Getting indexOf(25) of: [20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return -1 but got: 0

Getting lastIndexOf(20) of: [20]
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Getting lastIndexOf(25) of: [20]
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Getting indexOf(5) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return 0 but got: 6

Getting indexOf(10) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return 1 but got: 7

Getting indexOf(15) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return 2 but got: 8

Getting indexOf(20) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return 3 but got: 9

Getting indexOf(0) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return -1 but got: 0

Getting lastIndexOf(5) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Getting lastIndexOf(10) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Getting lastIndexOf(15) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Getting lastIndexOf(20) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Getting lastIndexOf(0) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Done - press enter key to end program

Comment: Try using a debugger, or at least put some `System.out.println` calls in your code to make sure the variables or whatever are what you think they are.  As it is, I can't help at all because there's no indication of what `copyRange(arr,start)` is *supposed* to return.  Plus, it appears that you are posting about multiple errors.  And StackOverflow is not a place where you can just throw a bunch of code at us and say "this isn't working, what's wrong?" without any attempt to track down the problem yourself.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`copyRange` always returns null:

```
int[] newList = null;
return newList;
```

`IndexOf` & `lastIndexOf`:

Read up on `IndexOutOfBoundsException` return the proper value accordingly

Think about it and make these fixes, we can't spoon feed every answer, there also may be other bugs that I am not addressing.